# Merging time stamps of different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Suppose I have two data frames such as:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-02-01"),as.Date("2019-02-28"), by="days"), 
                   Coyote=(rep(10,28)))

df2 <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-03-31"), by="days"),
                  Birds=(rep(2,90)))
```

How can I merge the two `Date`s column in `df1` without affecting the other variables?

Outcome desired:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-03-31"), by="days"), 
                   Coyote=c(rep(NA,31),rep(10,28),rep(NA,31)))

         Date Coyote
1  2019-01-01     NA
                  ...
31 2019-01-31     NA
32 2019-02-01     10
                  ...
59 2019-02-28     10
60 2019-03-01     NA
                  ...
90 2019-03-31     NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? (Just a sampling, the real results are 90 rows.)

```r
out <- merge(df1, df2[,"Date",drop=FALSE], by="Date", all=TRUE)

### and a sampling of the results, ordered
out[order(out$Date),][c(1:3, 37:39, 88:90),]
#          Date Coyote
# 1  2019-01-01     NA
# 2  2019-01-02     NA
# 3  2019-01-03     NA
# 37 2019-02-06     10
# 38 2019-02-07     10
# 39 2019-02-08     10
# 88 2019-03-29     NA
# 89 2019-03-30     NA
# 90 2019-03-31     NA
```

Comment: Nice base solution. No need for `full_join`. The `drop=FALSE` option does the trick for 2 columns df case.